# Excel macro concatenate result give wrong end result

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro that concatenates values from selected cells and puts it in an input box.

I am unable to remove the last comma before my parenthesis of the result in the input box.

Thanx for the help!

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim celCurrentCell As Range
    Dim celFirstCell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim txtTempText As String
    i = 0
    txtTempText = ""
    For Each celCurrentCell In Selection
        If i = 0 Then
            i = 1
            Set celFirstCell = celCurrentCell
        End If
        txtTempText = txtTempText & celCurrentCell.Value & "','"
    Next
    txtTempText = Left(txtTempText, Len(txtTempText) - 1)

    InputBox "Copier/coller le texte", "Concatenator", "('" + txtTempText + ")"
End Sub
```

Comment: Then subtract one more from the length: `Len(txtTempText) - 2`

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim celCurrentCell As Range
    Dim celFirstCell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim txtTempText As String, sep as string

    i = 0
    txtTempText = ""
    For Each celCurrentCell In Selection
        If i = 0 Then
            i = 1
            Set celFirstCell = celCurrentCell
        End If
        txtTempText = txtTempText & sep & celCurrentCell.Value
        sep = "','"
    Next

    InputBox "Copier/coller le texte", "Concatenator", "('" + txtTempText + "')"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are selecting multiple cells in a single row or multiple cells in a single column, this removes the loop.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim strTemp As String, sep As String

    sep = "','"
    If Selection.Rows.Count > Selection.Columns.Count Then
        strTemp = "('" & Join(Application.Transpose(Selection.Columns(1).Value2), sep) & "')"
    Else
        strTemp = "('" & Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Selection.Rows(1).Value2)), sep) & "')"
    End If
    Debug.Print strTemp

    InputBox "Copier/coller le texte", "Concatenator", strTemp

End Sub
```